# print array multidimensional php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an multidimensional array:

```
 Array
(
    [account] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 999856
                    [name] => Ice Cream
                    [description] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [accountId] => 7527391
                    [gain] => 8.1302399863
                    [absGain] => 8.13
                    [daily] => 0.18
                    [monthly] => 5.58
                    [withdrawals] => 0.00
                    [deposits] => 100000.00
                    [interest] => -278.46
                    [profit] => 8130.24
                    [balance] => 108130.24
                    [drawdown] => 26.78
                    [equity] => 102768.19
                    [demo] => true
                    [lastUpdateDate] => 09/26/2014 20:48
                    [creationDate] => 08/17/2014 21:00
                    [firstTradeDate] => 08/16/2014 00:00
                    [tracking] => 0
                    [views] => 3
                    [commission] => 0.00
                    [currency] => USD
                    [profitFactor] => 1.36
                    [pips] => -291.5
                    [invitationUrl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [server] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Other(MT4)
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1030189
                    [name] => Vanilla CupCake
                    [description] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [accountId] => 7276363
                    [gain] => 44.7620800233
                    [absGain] => 44.76
                    [daily] => 0.07
                    [monthly] => 2.23
                    [withdrawals] => 0.00
                    [deposits] => 100000.00
                    [interest] => -1837.49
                    [profit] => 44762.08
                    [balance] => 144762.08
                    [drawdown] => 12.43
                    [equity] => 144762.08
                    [demo] => true
                    [lastUpdateDate] => 09/26/2014 20:51
                    [creationDate] => 09/26/2014 16:19
                    [firstTradeDate] => 05/12/2013 00:00
                    [tracking] => 0
                    [views] => 1
                    [commission] => 0.00
                    [currency] => USD
                    [profitFactor] => 1.37
                    [pips] => -4302.1
                    [invitationUrl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [server] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Other(MT4)
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need to go and print the values ​​of [0] and [1] with foreach only prints the values ​​of [0].

```
//the foreach 
<?php 
foreach($real as $r => $val){ 
echo $val['id'];
echo $val['name'];
echo $val['accountId'];
echo $val['gain'];
echo $val['daily'];
echo $val['monthly'];
echo $val['balance'];

?>
```

this foreach print only values of [0]...Why not loops over the array [1]?

Comment: Can you please share the `foreach()`?

Comment: why do you "need to" do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
foreach($data['account'] as $key=>$val){
    echo $val['id'];
    echo $val['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 nested for loops. The inner one will have key value pair

If $a is your variable name then

```
foreach($a as $b)
{
  foreach($b as $val)
  {
    foreach($val as $key=>$vl)
    {
      echo $key.' '. $vl;
    }
  }
}
```